# How to open Html files too large for browsers and Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

The specific html files I want to open are generated by a seed farming tool that I didn't create. It logs the game's world generation process repeatedly into a log html file and lays it out
[when opened like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbwuO.png).
I've found that this takes up a lot of memory and when I leave the seed generator on for an hour or longer the generated log has takes up too much memory to be opened in a browser. I am able to open the html logs in notepad++ but all the text is in a single line, for medium sized files [I am able to use split lines and then I am able to use ctrl+f to find the specifics I want from a seed like this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYwi0.png).(56.38mb) However I've run into a problem where if I leave the seed farm running for even more time, like overnight for 8 hours then the file is too large for notepad++ to open it as the 1st line is 126,667,045 characters long crashing notepad++.(123.699mb) I have tried using VIM however it seems to mess up the formatting making it impossible to find the terms I want and using / to search up terms in VIM does not result in any match. I am not a programmer by any means but I am willing to download specific software to search for strong seeds in this video game.

Comment: EmEditor works fine for big files.

Comment: Notepad++ has a BigFiles plugin https://i.imgur.com/6Kj4N2d.png In the menu go to Plugins - Plugins Admin

Comment: UltraEdit handles any size of file. I use this.

Comment: Notepad++ should have zero problems opening a 123.699 MB text file. A 123 MB file is literally nothing in modern terms.

Comment: Word wrap turns the single line into many https://i.imgur.com/aBtmnwt.png